# A python program fails to execute in sublime text 3, but success in bash

Tags: python, bash, sublimetext3

```
#-*- encoding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)

text = "我们的世界充满了未知数。"  # Chinese

print( type(text) )        # unicode
print(text.encode('utf-8'))
print(text)                # an error occurs in sublime
```

The version of python is 2.7.6. The OS is Linux mint 17. `$LANG` in bash is `en_US.UTF-8`. In sublime text, <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> is used to run this   toy program. The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<type 'unicode'>
我们的世界充满了未知数。
  File "~/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(text)                # an error occurs
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "~/test.py"]
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/test.py", line 9, in <module>
<type 'unicode'>
我们的世界充满了未知数。
    print(text)                # an error occurs
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "~/test.py"]
```

In bash, eigher`python test.py` or `python -u test.py` runs correctly:

```
$ python test.py 
<type 'unicode'>
我们的世界充满了未知数。
我们的世界充满了未知数。
$ python -u test.py 
<type 'unicode'>
我们的世界充满了未知数。
我们的世界充满了未知数。
```

It really makes me wonder. <del>Is there any ways to run the program in sublime text correctly ?</del>

- Is there any difference between the environments of sublime and bash?
- why the outputs in sublime text is out-of-order？

Comment: You already ran it correctly - you just need to use `.encode()`.

Comment: @MattDMo My previous question is inaccurate. I have updated it.

Comment: Under SublimeText you're probably seeing some random interleaving of text printed to `stdout` and `stderr`. Does bash print the same string twice?

Comment: @roeland yes. I add the output in the question.

Comment: My guess is that sublime is providing the wrong locale to python when running the code. Have you tried asking for help at their forum?

Comment: @RedX Now I think it's the problem of bash.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305464/why-does-print-an-unicode-obj-in-ipython-occur-no-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime has a configuration problem.  Python uses the default `ascii` codec when it can't determine the terminal encoding.  It is figuring it out correctly in `bash` so it works.

If you set the environment variable `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` before launching sublime you can force Python to use that encoding when printing.  I'm not familiar with sublime so I can't suggest how to fix its configuration.