# Why does print an unicode obj in ipython occur no error?

Tags: python, bash, unicode

I have asked [A python program fails to execute in sublime text 3, but success in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302902/a-python-program-fails-to-execute-in-sublime-text-3-but-success-in-bash) . I did some research and found it's necessary to start a new question.

In python2.7, the `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is ascii:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[2]: 'ascii'
```

In my opinion, print an obj is equal to `print str(obj)`. If `obj` is unicode, it will be encoded to ascii. For example(test.py):

```
#-*- encoding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()  # ascii
print "你好"
print u"你好"  # should be an error occured: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec...
```

But there is no error occured in ipython:

```
In [3]: print "你好"
你好

In [4]: print u"你好"
你好
```

Why does print an unicode obj  in ipython occur no error? My understanding is not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing, the default encoding is used when only when Python can't determine the terminal encoding.  Both work in your case because the first `"你好"` is a byte string encoded in the terminal encoding already.  The second `u"你好"` is a Unicode string that will be encoded in the terminal encoding, which the former command already shows supports Chinese.

`ascii` is used when Python 2.X coerces a Unicode string into a byte string.  for example, the statement `u'你好'.decode('utf8')` is a common error where `.decode()` is being called on a Unicode string, but only byte strings have a `.decode()` method.  Python then attempts to encode the Unicode string using the default `ascii` codec to a byte string, so that `.decode()` can be called.

Example below, but note it is an *encode* error not a *decode* error:

```
>>> u'你好'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```